# Issue getting Salesforce Data Using REST API

Tags: rest-api, apexrest, connected-apps

Well, first am all new into the REST API's. I am not getting what I am doing wrong. Below are the steps I am following:

1. Created a Lightning Connected App and got CONSUMER_KEY and SECRET_KEY.
2. Hitting the below URL in my Browser to get AUTH_KEY: `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize? 
   response_type=code&client_id=CONSUMER_KEY&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL`
3. Hitting below URL to get ACCESS_TOKEN and REFRESH_TOKEN: `login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL&client_id=CONSUMER_KEY&client_secret=SECRET_KEY&code=AUTH_KEY`.
4. After getting the ACCESS_TOKEN and REFRESH_TOKEN, using Postman Tool or Hitting the below URL to Access data from Salesforce Org: `https://MY_INSTANCE.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v43.0/query?q=SELECT+name+from+Account?Bearer=ACCESS_TOKEN`

After hitting this URL either in Postman or Browser URL I am getting this below error:

`[
    {
        "message": "Session expired or invalid",
        "errorCode": "INVALID_SESSION_ID"
    }
]`

Comment: I think what I did wrong here is that the parameters will go in Headers, not in URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is indeed in step 4. The `ACCESS_TOKEN` must go in the Authorizatipn header. In Postman, for example, you would click on the headers section and add a new header with the key of Authorization, and the value of `Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN`. You would need to remove that from the URL in order for the query to work correctly as well, so the URL would be `https://MY_INSTANCE.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v43.0/query?q=SELECT+name+from+Account`.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps which are mentioned here http://www.v2force.com/blog/connected-apps/. It may help you to get Salesforce data using REST API.